# Return a global variable, use a string as the variable name

Tags: autohotkey

I have a function called `fillUI()` whose main purpose is to fill the UI that has been created. In my original script I need to go over more than 20 Edit Controls and fill them with content. The content is stored inside an array.

The problem that I am facing is that I am unaware of how "return" a global variable with content, whose variable name is made up from a string.

It's like saying `myVar1 := "Hello World"` is the original variable. Then I point to that variable with `varName := "myVar1"` and then change it with `varName := "foobar"` but `myVar1` will still be `Hello World` in the end..

Is such a thing possible?

```
; Start of script
#SingleInstance Force

FillUI()

Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y9 w350 h30 , %Text_1%
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y89 w350 h30 , %Text_2%
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y159 w350 h30 , %Text_3%

Gui, Show, w390 h278, Code testing
return

FillUI() {
    words := {1:"Hello World",2:"foobar",3:"lorem ipsum"}

    i := 1
    while(i <= words.MaxIndex()) {
        global variable_name := "Text_" i
        word := words[i]

        ; I need to return a variable here whose variable name needs to be something like "Text_X" and whose content is %word%
        ; This is in order to fill the UI above
        ;
        ; Is this achievable?
        variable_name := word
        i++
    }
}

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
return

; End of script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.
The `global` at the start of the script declares all variables that are used in that script as global, hence the variables that are used only inside the FillUI()function are declared using `local`

```
; Start of script
#SingleInstance Force

FillUI()

Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y9 w350 h30 , %Text_1%
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y89 w350 h30 , %Text_2%
Gui, Add, Edit, x12 y159 w350 h30 , %Text_3%

Gui, Show, w390 h278, Code testing
return

FillUI() {
    global
    local words := {1:"Hello World",2:"foobar",3:"lorem ipsum"}

    local i := 1
    while(i <= words.MaxIndex()) {


        word := words[i]
     ;I need to return a variable here whose variable name needs to be something like "Text_X" and whose content is %word%
        ; This is in order to fill the UI above
        ;
        ; Is this achievable?
        Text_%i% := word

        i++
    }
}

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
return
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!